# stuck at displaying a PHP paginator

Tags: php, pagination

I'm trying to create a paginator. I have created a paginator class with properties you can see below. But now I'm trying to display the paginator, but I'm completely stuck on different loops (perhaps I should just go to bed :P) and stuff.

The important properties are:

```
windows_size // the amount of pages visible
num_pages // the total number of pages
current_page // the currently selected page
```

I have the following object:

```
o: (Paginator)
 ->item_count  : 295
   page_size   : 50
   window_size : 5
   num_pages   : 10
   current_page: 1
   first_index : 50
```

And I want to display:

[1] 2 3 4 5 ...

Or I have:

```
o: (Paginator)
 ->item_count  : 295
   page_size   : 50
   window_size : 5
   num_pages   : 10
   current_page: 5
   first_index : 50
```

... 3 4 [5] 6 7...

Or I have:

```
o: (Paginator)
 ->item_count  : 295
   page_size   : 50
   window_size : 5
   num_pages   : 10
   current_page: 9
   first_index : 50
```

... 6 7 8 [9] 10

How would I get this to be displayed?

END RESULTS (many thanks to: Wh1T3h4Ck5!)

http://pastebin.com/2KzL1Tn6

Comment: a snippet from a project I made : http://pastebin.com/A8jAm3Xf

Comment: what is page_size? first_index? I cant see relation between item_count, num_pages  and page_size,

Comment: As stated page_size isn't important for this problem. FYI page_size is the number of items on a single page.

Comment: If number of items is 50 (in your example), and you have 295 items, you can create 6 pages not 10 (num_pages). That's why I was confused.

Comment: :) My bad. I just changed the (for me) important properties by hand for the example. Ok ok hang me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, it's very simple piece of code.

You can use something like this.

```
function myPaginator($total_items, $items_per_page, $visible_pages_pad, $active_page) {
  $res = '';
  if ($items_per_page > 0 && $active_page > 0 && $visible_pages_pad) {
  $max_page = floor($total_items/$items_per_page);
  if ($total_items % $items_per_page > 0) $max_page++;
    if ($active_page <= $max_page) {
      $visible_pages = $visible_pages_pad * 2 + 1;
      if ($max_page <= $visible_pages) {
        $minp = 1; 
        $maxp = $max_page;
        }
      else {
        $minp = $active_page - $visible_pages_pad;
        if ($minp < 1) $minp = 1;
        $maxp = $minp + $visible_pages - 1;
        if ($maxp > $max_page) {
          $maxp = $max_page;
          $minp = $maxp - $visible_pages + 1;
          }
        } 
      for ($i = $minp; $i <= $maxp; $i++) {
        $page = $i == $active_page ? "[$i]" : $i; // create links here
        $res .= "$page ";
        }
      $res = trim($res);
      if ($minp > 1) $res = '... ' . $res; // left dots
      if ($maxp < $max_page) $res .= ' ...'; // right dots
      }
    }
  return $res == '' ? false : $res;
  }
```

---

**Parameters:**

- **$total_items** - total number of items in list
- **$items_per_page** - how menu items you want on page
- **$visible_pages_pad** - left/right padding (this value * 2 + 1 = number of paginator items)
- **$active_page** - selected page in paginator

---

**Result:**

> Function myPaginator() returns
>   **false** if something is wrong, otherwise returns string.

---

**Limitations:**

- all parameters should be integers
- $items_per_page > 0
- $visible_pages_pad > 0
- 1 <= $active_page <= {TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES}

---

**Usage:**

```
$total_items = 250;      // total items
$items_per_page = 20;    // 250/20 = 13 pages
$visible_pages_pad = 2;  // 5 pages visible in paginator (2*2+1)

$active_page = 1;  
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: [1] 2 3 4 5 ...

$active_page = 2;    
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: 1 [2] 3 4 5 ...

$active_page = 3;    
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: 1 2 [3] 4 5 ...

$active_page = 6;      
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: ... 4 5 [6] 7 8 ...

$active_page = 11;  
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: ... 9 10 [11] 12 13

$active_page = 12;        
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: ... 9 10 11 [12] 13

$active_page = 13;      
echo myPaginator($total_items,$items_per_page,$visible_pages_pad,$active_page);
// output: ... 9 10 11 12 [13]
```

Note: $visible_pages_pad is number of pages in paginator left/right of the active-page number.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. This code sure looks like the code I wrote yesterday. Gonna check it out where I went totally stupid. :P

Comment: One thing I notice it you do:  `$max_page = floor($total_items/$items_per_page);
        if ($total_items % $items_per_page > 0) $max_page++;`. Why don't you just do: `ceil($total_items/$items_per_page);`?

Comment: @PeeHaa - Good point. It was 4:00 AM here, I totally forgot about ceil() and I wrote it in about 5-10 minutes. Cheers

Comment: @ Wh1T3h4Ck5: hehehe tell me about it. I think I got stuck in the first place cause I should have gone to bed :) Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for a phenomenally thorough answer. You seem to have basically covered the entire theory of pagination. ;)