# PHP Pagination for each ten pages without SQL, MYSQL

Tags: php, pagination

I've searched my issue through internet but I coudn't find satisfying solution.

I'm try to generate pagination depend on page names on my website. 
At code below I achieved this but I also want to show limited pages like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4qw.png)

I'm not php coder and my basic code is here...

```
function Pagination($TotalPage)
{
$PageName= substr(basename ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) , 0, (strlen(basename ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) )-3));

for ($x = 1; $x <= $TotalPage; $x++)
{
echo ltrim((sprintf('<a href="%s_%03d">%03d</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PageName, $x, $x)));
}
}
```

(I am retrieving page link from file name and increase them one by one)

When this code runs it shows all of pages like this (below of page): http://www.mcuma.com/doku.php/mesnevi/birinci_cilt_001

If any one help to modify code according my needing, I'll be very glad.

Best regards,

Mete

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683655/stuck-at-displaying-a-php-paginator/5685220#5685220) may help. Here you can find `PHP` code and example how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination you have to know which page you're on. Those are the last three digits if I understand correctly. So:

```
$currentpage = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], -3);
```

Now it depends on what you want to do. If you want the presentation as in the screenshot. Since the trim and sprintf is way too long for me to type, I'll just write `link(pagename, number, caption)` and assume such a function exists

```
$first = 1; // this is a magic var.
$range = 3; // as is this.

$prev = max($currentpage-1, $first);            // find prev
$low = max($currentpage-$range, $first+1);      // clip low
$high = min($currentpage+$range, $TotalPage-1); // clip high
$next = min($currentpage+1, $TotalPage);        // find next

link($PageName, $prev, '&laquo;');
link($PageName, $first, $first);
if ($low-1 != $first) { echo '...'; }
for($x = $low; $x <= $high; $x++) {
  link($PageName, $x, $x);
}
if ($high+1 != $TotalPage) { echo '...'; }
link($pageName, $TotalPage, $TotalPage);
link($PageName, $next, '&raquo;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much **Jakumi**,
according to your instructive answer, I only changed link() function in your coding because of my PHP release doesn't support link() function.

It may be long and not clever but it works fine for me. 
Thank you again my friend **Jakumi**.

```
function PG($TP)
{
$PN= substr(basename ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) , 0, (strlen(basename (      $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) )-3)); // page name  
$currentpage = intval(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], -2)); // page number as integer 

$first = 1; // this is a magic var.
$range = 10; // as is this. 

$prev = max($currentpage-1, $first);       // find prev
$low = max($currentpage-$range, $first+1); // clip low
$high = min($currentpage+$range, $TP-1); // clip high
$next = min($currentpage+1, $TP);        // find next

echo ltrim(sprintf('<a href="%s_%02d">&laquo;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PN,  $prev, $prev)); 
echo ltrim(sprintf('<a href="%s_%02d">%02d</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PN, $first, $first));   

if ($low-1 != $first) { echo '... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; }
for($x = $low; $x <= $high; $x++) {
echo ltrim(sprintf('<a href="%s_%02d">%02d</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PN, $x, $x));   
 }
 if ($high+1 != $TP) { echo '... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; }

 echo ltrim(sprintf('<a href="%s_%02d">%02d</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PN, $TP, $TP));    
 echo ltrim(sprintf('<a href="%s_%02d">&raquo;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $PN, $next, $next)); 
 }
```